# jQuery - css active

Tags: jquery, css, menu

`enter code here`I have a big problem with the jquery. When I click in one link in the my menu, it should be active (with a yellow color for example) and the other links should be equal to the original (example: black).Below is my css:

```
.graphite .menuBar {font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif; border-top: 1px solid #111; border-right: 0px solid #111; border-left: 1px solid #111; display:table-cell;}
.graphite .menuBar a {padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px; background: #0C0C0C url(images/bg_black.png) repeat-x 0 -1px; text-decoration:none; display: block; color: #ddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #222; border-top: 1px solid #777; position: relative;}
.graphite .menuBar div {background: #0078AE;}
.graphite .menuBar a:hover {background: #006599; color: #fff;}
.graphite .menuBar .highlight { background:#006599; color: #fff; }
```

On the side of jquery:

```
$('div.menuBar > a').click().addClass(""); //To the original tabs
$('a[id="Clients"]').each(function () { //when click in tab Clients
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
$('a[id="supplier"]').each(function () { //when click in tab supplier
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

What I mean is when I click in the clients tab, it should be with the class (.Highlight)

If you click in tab suppliers should be with the class (.Highlight active) and the other tabs with the original class.
Is it possible?
:...UPGRADE:
the menu is on this page:Header.cshtml

```
@model MWA.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (Model.message == "" || Model.message == null)){
using (Html.BeginForm("updateLanguage", "Header", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "headerForm" })){
<input type="hidden" id="hdOrga" name="hdOrga" value="@Model.Orga.orgaID" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdUtzID" name="hdUtzID" value="@Model.User.userID" />
<div class="div-table-header"> 
    <div class="div-table-header-row">
        <div class="div-table-header-col" style="width:5%; padding-left:10px">@MWA.Resources.Shared._Header.Orga:  </div>
        <div class="div-table-header-col" style="width:40%"><strong>@Model.Orga.orgaName</strong></div>
        <div class="div-table-header-col-right" style="width:55%">@MWA.Resources.Shared._LogOnPartial.Heading, <strong>@Html.ActionLink(@User.Identity.Name, "SignOut", "Account") </strong></div>
        <!--div class="div-table-header-col-right" style="width:10%;">@Html.ActionLink("SignOut", "SignOut", "Account")</div-->      
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-header-row">
        <div class="div-table-header-col" style="padding-left:10px">@MWA.Resources.Shared._Header.Comp:  </div>
@{  if (Model.Companies.Count() == 1)
    { 
        <div class="div-table-header-col"><strong>@Model.Companies.FirstOrDefault().companyName</strong></div>
    }
else
    {
        <div class="div-table-header-col"> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedCompany, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "companyID", "companyName"))  </div>
    } 
}
        <div class="div-table-header-col-right">@MWA.Resources.Shared._LogOnPartial.Lang: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedLanguage, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "lang", "langName", Model.selectedLanguage))</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div-table-header"> 
    <div class="div-table-header-row-menu">
        <div class="div-table-header-col-menu">
            <div class="graphite">
                @foreach (var app in Model.Appl)
    {
                <div class="menuBar">@Html.ActionLink((string)app.applicationName, "Index", (string)app.controler, new { app = app.applicationID }, new { id = (string)app.applicationName })</div>
    }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}   <!--Html.BeginForm-->
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/zgSDG/embedded/result/ ?

Comment: yes? do you have a code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/zgSDG/  here you go.

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique for each of your anchors. I'd suggest selecting it based on your html.

e.g

```
$('.menubar a').click(function (e) { //when click in tab Clients
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menubar a').removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
$('div.menuBar').on('click','.menuBar > a', function(){
  $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings('a').removeClass('highlight');
})
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/KCN5K/

Answer (score 1):

**jquery:**

```
$('div.menuBar > a').click(function(){
   $('.highlight').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass('highlight') });
   $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```